# Change object value in javascript from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults = {
    adminBarHeight:28,
    overlayOpacity: 0.8,
    borderSize: 10,
    imageArray: new Array,
    activeImage: null,
    inprogress: false, //this is an internal state variable. don't touch.
    widthCurrent: 250,
    heightCurrent: 250,
    xScale: 1,
    yScale: 1,
    displayTitle: true,
    disableNavbarLinks: true,
    loopImages: true,
    imageClickClose: true,
    jsonData: null,
    jsonDataParser: null,
    followScroll: false,
    isIE8: false  //toyNN:internal value only
};
```

When I adjust **borderSize** I get the effect I want however I need to be able to adjust this from another script rather than just changing the value above because I need to leave the code above unchanged as it may be overwritten during updates. How can I do this

I tried

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults[borderSize] = 0;
```

but it had no effect.

The code is from WP Lightbox 2.

Comment: You need to use a string accessor there. With your shown tried version, javascript is looking for the variable `borderSize` and if it does not exist, then it will fail because you are using `undefined` as the index reference. You probably wanted to use `"borderSize"` :)

Comment: Are you calling the light box first, and initializing it?

Answer (score 1):

It's:

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults['borderSize']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults['borderSize'] = 0;
```

or

```
$.fn.lightbox.defaults.borderSize = 0;
```

And ensure that ***this script is loaded after***